# Solve Bufferedreader blocking

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I have a read-Method which reads Inputstream from a socket-connection:

```
private String read(Socket socket) throws IOException {     
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    char[] buf = new char[BUF_SIZE];
    int n = br.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE); // blocking
    String msg = new String(buf, 0, n);
    return msg;     
}
```

Now the read-Method of Bufferedreader is blocking. I have to solve this. What can i do.

I've tried:

```
while(br.ready()) {
        char[] buf = new char[BUF_SIZE];
        int n = br.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE); // blocking
        msg = new String(buf, 0, n);
}
```

But this is giving me folowing error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

What im doing wrong?

EDIT: Closing the Socket-Connection is not an option

Comment: What do you mean by "solve this"? Blocking isn't inherently a problem. Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: Because the client has to listen for input without causing a timeout. This is the requirement for this task.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to fix. Is the timeout to short and the job aborts when you want it to continue trying or is it too long and it doesn't let other code run while it waits for input or is it something else entirely. If you could describe the *whole* system and how it behaves right now vs. how you **want** it to behave instead, that would probably help.